# Changing shell of windows 7 login

Tags: windows-7, vmware-view, windows-registry, login

I am currently trying to get a windows thin client to log directly into VMWare.  Essentially want to take [These directions](https://sites.sas.upenn.edu/jasonrw/blog/2013/03/repurpose-old-pc-vmware-view-thin-client) which are for Win XP and use them on a Win 7 machine.  There is no winlogon folder in the registry and the wswc.exe no longer seems to exist in VMWare View 5.1.

Any push in the right directions would be appreciated.  Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
    Shell (REG_SZ) = explorer.exe
```

Change that to notepad.exe if you want to use Notepad as your shell (just an example.) All those instructions were missing was `CurrentVersion`. Probably just a typo.

As for the new name of the VMware View 5.1 executable... I don't know off the top of my head what it is... can't you just... look in your installation directory and find out?

Comment: Thank you. There are two exe's in the install folder, will give them both a shot and see which yields the proper results.